# Jacoco agent faild to start on tomcat9: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 'bootstrap' attempted duplicate class definition for java.lang.$JaCoCo

Tags: java, linux, jacoco, tomcat9

When I try to start my tomcat 9 server on linux I have this error:

```
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_4a7f17c.core.runtime.InjectedClassRuntime$Lookup.defineClass(InjectedClassRuntime.java:134)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_4a7f17c.core.runtime.InjectedClassRuntime.startup(InjectedClassRuntime.java:54)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_4a7f17c.PreMain.premain(PreMain.java:50)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 'bootstrap' attempted duplicate class definition for java.lang.$JaCoCo. (java.lang.$JaCoCo is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2131)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:962)
        ... 13 more
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
```

I use this command line:
`-javaagent:/home/jenkins/tools/jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar=port=6300,destfile=/home/jenkins/jacoco/jacoco.exec,output=tcpserver,includes=myPackage.*,append=false`

I am using OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.19.7.1, the latest version of tomcat9 and jacoco 0.8.10.

I have the same configuration on windows and it works fine. My application is a war buit with maven and I don't have any problems on windows.

I tried to change my tomcat version and my JDK version but I still have the same problem. I don't find any solutions on the web.
I have no Jacoco dependencies in my pom.xml

Comment: rt.jar contains the 'bootstrap' Core SE classes in the JRE runtime , However , first point is the class name $JaCoCo probably should not start with "$" its usually the start of a nested subclass name!    $JaCoCo is the "target"   InvocationTargetException    ,  too if it needs to be placed amongst the java.base/ in the Core classes then the name should be changed and java.base configuration for the add in should be notified to the bootstrap on startup.

Comment: java.lang.LinkageError , it failed to copy the class file for $JaCoCo from the java.lang folder after rt.jar was expanded , perhaps after jvm startup put the class in before calling the main class or put it to the head of the jar list on the command line to extract it before it is called for use. Appears more the first thought ffor the LinkageError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I solved my problem by changing:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dlogback.ContextSelector=JNDI -Xms2G -Xmx16G -javaagent:/home/jenkins/tools/jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar=port=6300,destfile=/home/jenkins/jacoco/jacoco.exec,output=tcpserver,includes=com.worldline.*,address=localhost,append=false"
```

By:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dlogback.ContextSelector=JNDI -Xms2G -Xmx16G -javaagent:/home/jenkins/tools/jacoco/lib/jacocoagent.jar=port=6300,destfile=/home/jenkins/jacoco/jacoco.exec,output=tcpserver,includes=com.worldline.*,address=localhost,append=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage of more than one JaCoCo agent in one JVM is not allowed.

For example execution of

```
java -javaagent:jacoco-0.8.10/lib/jacocoagent.jar -version
```

leads to

```
openjdk version "11.0.17" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-11.0.17+8 (build 11.0.17+8, mixed mode)
```

whereas execution of

```
java -javaagent:jacoco-0.8.10/lib/jacocoagent.jar -javaagent:jacoco-0.8.10/lib/jacocoagent.jar -version
```

leads to exactly the same error that you see

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:513)
        at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_4a7f17c.core.runtime.InjectedClassRuntime$Lookup.defineClass(InjectedClassRuntime.java:134)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_4a7f17c.core.runtime.InjectedClassRuntime.startup(InjectedClassRuntime.java:54)
        at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_4a7f17c.PreMain.premain(PreMain.java:50)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader 'bootstrap' attempted duplicate class definition for java.lang.$JaCoCo. (java.lang.$JaCoCo is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.System$2.defineClass(System.java:2131)
        at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.defineClass(MethodHandles.java:962)
        ... 13 more
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at ./src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
```

Thus search what in your configuration leads to several `-javaagent`